# Device's bluetooth is not visible from iPhone, but it visible from Android

Tags: ios

I have a device with amp'edRF bluetooth module. My iphone doesn't see it. But from Android and other devices it is visible. What may cause this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Is this related to programming? Is it Bluetooth Low-Energy? Else, is it MFi?

Comment: It's OK.cseewwcwcdwcwdcwcw